# How do you play an mp3 in a Mac Application in Xcode 4.2

Tags: cocoa, mp3, core-audio

I'm trying to play an mp3 in a Mac Application in Xcode 4.2. How would I do this?

Comment: I'm assuming you're not trying to play the MP3 in the IDE itself. Are you coding a new Cocoa Application?

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to code a new Cocoa application. I need it to play a mp3 when a button is pressed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not giving us much to work with...

If you just want a simple sound, use [NSSound](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSSound_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

```
NSString *resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"fn" ofType:@"mp3"];
NSSound *sound = [[NSSound alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:resourcePath byReference:YES];
[sound play];
// wait for the sound to play before you release these...
```

With NSSound, the sound plays concurrently with your code. A common mistake is to release the sound or resource while it is still playing. Don't do that.

You can also use [QTMovie](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/QuickTime/Reference/QTKitFramework/Classes/QTMovie_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003799) in [QTKit](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/QuickTime/Reference/QTCocoaObjCKit/_index.html):

```
NSError *err = nil;
QTMovie *sound = [[QTMovie movieWithFile:@"fn.mp3" error:&err] retain];
[sound play];
```

For more demanding sounds, use [CoreAudio](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/CoreAudioOverview/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: @t3hcakeman: 'didn't work' is not very helpful. Did the resource file get found by the first line? Did you add the .mp3 file to your app's bundle? Right click (option click) on the target folder (below the project folder) and select 'Add files to ...' and select your .mp3 file. The NSSound family is biased towards alerts and such with bundle / resource based sound files.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [QTKit](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/quicktime/Reference/QTCocoaObjCKit/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001164) framework and the [QTMovie](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/quicktime/Reference/QTKitFramework/Classes/QTMovie_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class.